# What's the different between `plusAssign` and `add` for mutableList (or `put` for mutableMap)

Tags: kotlin, collections

In mutableList, we could `add`. and mutableMap we could `put`.

However I notice we could now also have `plusAssign` for them both. Checking under the hood, they are just `add` or `put`. What's the use of `plusAssign`?

```
public inline operator fun <T> MutableCollection<in T>.plusAssign(element: T) {
    this.add(element)
}

public inline operator fun <K, V> MutableMap<in K, in V>.plusAssign(pair: Pair<K, V>) {
    put(pair.first, pair.second)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plusAssign` is a function for overloading `+=` operator.

In the implementation for `MutableList`, this function adds an item to the list. For `MutableMap` puts a pair to the map.

```
val ml = mutableListOf(1)
ml += 2 // will be translated to `ml.plusAssign(2)`
println(ml) // [1, 2]
```

[operator-overloading](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#operator-overloading)

Comment: Operational wise it is the same as `add`?

Comment: @Elye it depends on how this function is implemented, for `MutableList` yes, it the same as `add`, but allows you to use `+=` operator for `MutableList`